# function scale() in R doesn't scale the data symmetrically

Tags: r

I apologize if my question is simple. I tried to find the answer but I didn't find much info.

I use the scale() function in R to scale my data. What I don't understand is that when I plot my scaled data using matplot() it seems my scaled data aren't symmetric. which means the range of the sacled data is `-1,-0.5,0,0.5,1,1.5`. As I know, we scale the data to mean zero and standard deviation s. So my data should have a deviation of s from mean but here I have a deviation of 1.5 and a deviation of -1. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data are not symmetric around their mean.

Compare the following:

```
x <- runif(1000)  # symmetric around 0.5
y <- rexp(1000)  # not symmetric around 1 at all

summary(scale(x))
summary(scale(y))
```

Comment: Thank you. Is that ok? Or should data always be symmetric?